# Cannot insert newline in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, character, newline

How do I insert a newline character in JavaScript? The below code displays everything in one line even when using the newline character in for loop

```
function isEven(number)
{
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

for (let i=0;i<=30;i++)
{
    if (isEven(i) == 1)
    {
        document.write(i + " even\n");

    }
    else {
        document.write(i + " odd\n");

    }

}
```

Comment: Outputting a newline in an HTML page won't introduce a new line in an HTML document. use <br/> instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `document.write`, you should use [`<br>: The Line Break element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br#:%7E:text=The%20HTML%20element%20produces,division%20of%20lines%20is%20significant.):

```js
function isEven(number)
{
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

for (let i=0;i<=30;i++)
{
    if (isEven(i) == 1)
    {
        document.write(i + " even<br>");

    }
    else {
        document.write(i + " odd<br>");

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think an answer should promote bad practices. The OP is obviously a beginner and seems to use outdated material. It is grossly negligent to simply answer the question without pointing out that document.write should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use method `console.log();` instead of `document.write();`

Answer (score 1):

I would do it without using document.write - I would create a ul and build a string that encompasses all the li's and determine whether each is odd ;/ even. Then insert that string into the innerHTM of the ul. The advatage of this is  that you are only altering the DOM on once - instead of on each iteration, and using li's eliminates the need for line-breaks since the li's are already block level elements.

I would also simplify the odd / even checking logic to return the text based on the modulus operator thatbecomes the index of the option.

```js
function isEven(number) {
 const options = ['odd', 'even'];
 return options[number % 2];
}

let listStr = '';

for (let i=0;i<=30;i++) {
 listStr += '<li>' + i + ' - '  + isEven(i) + '</li>';
}

document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = listStr;
```

```css
#results {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It generally is considered bad practice to use `document.write` you shouldn't use it at all.

In your case you could create an html string and then append it to the documents body (or wherever you want your result).

Like Mamum said: you need to use a `<br>` tag which the Browser renders as a line break.

We use [Element.insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert the html code to the body.

```js
let html = "";

for (let i=0;i<=30;i++)
{
    if (isEven(i) == 1)
    {
        html += i + " even<br>";

    }
    else {
        html += i + "  odd<br>";

    }

}
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
```